# Matlab Readtable Slow in Loop

Tags: excel, performance, matlab, loops, activex

I have a loop that reads several tabs (as chosen by optionsList) of an xls workbook. It takes a long time to run. I am not sure if it is because it is opening and closing excel actxserver for each loop? The code is below:

```
    for ii=1:length(optionsList);

        optionsTables.(optionsList{ii})=readtable(inputFile,'Sheet', optionsList{ii},'ReadRowNames',true);


    end
```

What options do I have to optimise this?

I have tried:

```
Excel = actxserver ('Excel.Application'); 
if ~exist(inputFile,'file') 
    ExcelWorkbook = Excel.Workbooks.Add; 
    ExcelWorkbook.SaveAs(inputFile,1); 
    ExcelWorkbook.Close(false); 
end 
Excel.Workbooks.Open(inputFile); 
tic
for ii=1:length(optionsList);

    optionsTables.(optionsList{ii})=readtable(inputFile,'Sheet', optionsList{ii},'ReadRowNames',true);

end
Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Save; 
Excel.Quit 
Excel.delete 
clear Excel

toc
```

Which does not shorten the run time

[image: Profile results attached]

Comment: Try xlsread with `basic` option set, it is typically faster.

Comment: What size is your data? Have you profiled your code?

Comment: About 20 tabs of about 20 rows x 5 columns. So not a lot of data, just a lot of opening and closing of tabs? I am not familiar with profiling. The number of tabs is likely to multiply.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/profile.html

Comment: The `readtable` function calls `xlsread` internally so you're basically just looping `xlsread`. Since you are already opening the ActiveX interface (but not using it at all) it will likely be faster to read your data as a cell array and convert to a table explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, [`readtable`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html) internally calls [`xlsread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html) to read in Excel data. It's down the rabbit hole a bit (`readtable -> table -> readfromfile -> readxlsfile -> xlsread`) but you can see it in the profiler. Though it also utilizes ActiveX for speed, it sets up and destroys this interface for every call. With repeated calls this often leads to a significant "waste" of CPU time.

One potential alternative is to utilize a single ActiveX connection and use your loop to read each sheet, then convert into a table. This seems like what you were attempting with the second example with `readtable`.

An example of this approach:

```
% Generate sample data file, lazy approach
A = rand(10);
for ii = 1:10
    sheetname = sprintf('Tab_%u', ii);
    xlswrite('asdf.xlsx', A, sheetname);
end

% Set up import parameters
optionsList = {'Tab_1', 'Tab_3', 'Tab_5', 'Tab_7', 'Tab_10'};

% Use single ActiveX instance to read in desired data
exl = actxserver('excel.application');
exlWkbk = exl.Workbooks;
exlFile = exlWkbk.Open(fullfile(cd, 'asdf.xlsx'));

% Read the data from the sheet, then convert to table
for ii = 1:length(optionsList)
    currentSheet = exlFile.Sheets.Item(optionsList{ii});
    optionsTables.(optionsList{ii}) = cell2table(currentSheet.UsedRange.Value);
end

% Clean up
exlFile.Close(false);  
exl.Quit();
exl.delete();
clear exl
```

Which returns:

```
optionsTables = 

     Tab_1: [10x10 table]
     Tab_3: [10x10 table]
     Tab_5: [10x10 table]
     Tab_7: [10x10 table]
    Tab_10: [10x10 table]
```

I haven't had the opportunity to benchmark this against the other approach, but it *should* be faster.

Comment: I get the following errors repeated: Warning: Out of range or non-integer values truncated during conversion to
character. 
> In matlab.internal.table.container2vars (line 57)
  In cell2table (line 34). Is this because some entries are strings?

Comment: @Mary No. If the contents of the Excel column are not a homogeneous data type then the column of the table is just cast as a cell array. I would suspect the error stems from the row and/or column headers you are attempting to use. What is the *exact* code that generates the warning?

Comment: The code is several files and is quite long. The headers in the excel file are: control value default toggle definition. It is the value column and all the rows with "1" in the toggle column that are kept to create a table. Could these names be the issue?

Comment: Of course it is, which is why it's highly recommended you ask your question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so users trying to help you don't have to play 20 questions. If you read the [documentation for `table`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html) you will see that column names must be valid MATLAB variable names; no leading numbers, no spaces, no special characters, etc. If these are present when MATLAB attempts to generate the table, it will throw a warning and attempt to generate a valid string.

Comment: ah ok.  Thought that was the complete set of information needed to solve my particular question. Good to know. Thanks

Comment: However I do not see a problem with any of these names: "control" "value" "default" "toggle" "definition" which are each a column header. Changing these names results in the same errors

Comment: Again, I cannot help you if I can't reproduce the issue. And this is a *warning*, not an *error*. Execution was not halted, compare the imported table to your Excel file to see what has changed.

Comment: It works for me. I just get the error following your suggestions. If you apply that code (at the bottom of the question if you have not seen it) to your excel file it would work in the same way for you too.